# POST using query parameter versus writeBytes

Tags: web, service

I am new to Web Service. I am trying to understand the server-side impact of posting requests from the client-side. If I use CASE 1 approach, I can retrieve the value from URL query parameter.

However, if the post is happening using the second approach, how does the server receive this data? In header, query parameter, or as a stream?

Case - 1

```
        URL url = url("http://serviceendpoint?q=value");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Case -2

```
        URL   url = url("http://serviceendpoint");  
        String urlParameters="value";

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        //Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case 2, the value of the `urlParameters` variable (the string "value") will be written as the body of the POST request. You'd retrieve it on the server side from the raw request body. Since you wrote straight data the server won't see form field or parameter name/value pairs that it can parse, the server code will have to read the request body as data and do the appropriate thing with it. Depending on the server you may also need to set the MIME content type of the request to "text/plain" or another type that indicates what kind of data is present, the standard POST content types of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "multipart/form-data" would cause the server to try to parse the body for name/value pairs in the specified encoding which'll fail.